# pointer in Objective-C

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I've been learning iOS for about several months, I find that I should use **pointer** to objects of many Objective-C types.
But there are some cases that should not use pointer such as "NSInteger" "CGPoint" "BOOL"...
So the questions is : On which conditions should I use a pointer ? and what's the purpose of using a pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSInteger, CGPoint, etc.. are not Objective-C Objects.
They are structs or typedefs.

You must use pointers with Object types.
You can use pointers with the other (C) types

Answer (score 0):

You use a pointer to everything that is an object.